# Incompatibility between 'tikzscale' and tikz 'circuits' library

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, tikz-circuit-lib, tikzscale

I want to include a figure containing an electrical circuit in my file. To ensure the correct filesize I use tikzscale `includegraphics` command. However, this yields an error for some of the elements in my figure. Is there a way to fix it?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{figure1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,set inductor graphic = var inductor IEC
graphic]
\draw (0,0) to[inductor] (2,0) to[voltage source] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{figure1.tikz} % Works fine
\bigskip
\includegraphics{figure1.tikz} % Breaks the inductor

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
pdflatex> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/var inductor IECgraphic' 
pdflatex> and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
pdflatex> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

And the output looks like this:
[image: MWE]

Comment: Don't break a line in the middle of a keyword.  (Why this causes a problem is another matter.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Wow, thats it. I feel incredibly stupid right now :D Thanks a lot and feel free to post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently tikzscale is more sensitive to line breaks than `\input`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{figure1.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,set inductor graphic = var inductor IEC graphic]
\draw (0,0) to[inductor] (2,0) to[voltage source] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{figure1.tikz} % Works fine
\bigskip
\includegraphics{figure1.tikz} % Breaks the inductor

\end{document}
```